# How to close a Inputstream not defined by InputStream but directly used inside a method?

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, jsch

I am saving a document to the network drive through SFTP server by using JSCH. In that I have a some method like this to save document which take two parameters `inputStream` and `path to save the stream into a file which is a string.`.

```
String message="I am saving this file to the shared drive";
channelSftp.put(new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes()),pathFromChannel+"/"+"file.txt");
```

So, In the above code I am directly using

`1. new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes())`

instead of assigning it to some inputStream i.e

```
2 .InputStream in=new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes());
```

If I do something like this I can close this Stream by doing `is.close();`. But How can close an `Inputstream` or `outputStream` when I directly use without defining it ? Or don't I need to close this?

Comment: Why don't you assign it to a variable, pass it in, then close it? Also, byteareaysyreams don't need to be closed

Comment: So is it the best practice to assign stream to some variable instead of directly using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to close `ByteArrayInputStream`  - this is just an array, and not socket IO

Comment: What if I directly  use any other socket stream like 'FileInputStream' without assigning to a variable?How to close that at that time?or is it proper to assign the stream to some variable then use it and close it?

Comment: In this case you must assign it to variable and close it in finally statement. See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html - this commes with java 8 first